# Notification center - notification not appearing in notification center when they received on active app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, notificationcenter

I need that all notification will apear in notification center , and in my app only the notification received from background or when app is closed is presented in notification center. 
Is that my problem ?
How to add a notification to notification center from code ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make remote notification appear in notification center when app is in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058418/how-to-make-remote-notification-appear-in-notification-center-when-app-is-in-the)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `postNotification:`, `postNotificationName:object:` or `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` methods to post notification from your code

See [NSNotificationCenter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more informations

Hope it helps!

Comment: I also want same thing . when my app is open i dont want any alert view .just want showing the notification in notification center .please update if any one have solution .

Answer (score 1):

Check if application is active when you receive notification

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
```

If active you can show alert or use [Local notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1) to add message in Notification center. Please note user can remove app from Notification Center as well chose alert not banner from settings.