# How to make remote notification appear in notification center when app is in the foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

When my app in in the foreground, it receives a push notification from my server, triggers my `UNNotificationServiceExtension`, and then triggers `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`. The notification appears at the top of the app for a couple seconds, but when I swipe the top of the phone to see the notification center, the notification isn't there.

If my phone is locked or the app is in the background while I receive the notification, then it does appear in the notification center.

How do I make the notification appear in the notification center while the app is in the foreground?

Comment: Can you share your userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:) implementation?

Comment: @BurakAkkaş All I have is the single line: `completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think adding `.list` should do the trick

```
completionHandler([.badge, .banner, .sound, .list])
```

You can read more about `UNNotificationPresentationOptions` [here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions)

Comment: Wow thank you. I knew I was missing some small detail, but I didn't see any examples using the .list field. Was stuck on this for way longer than I'd like to admit.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I always check all the available options in an Enum before using it, saves a lot of headache later.

Comment: I would like this as well. I am using Obj C. I will keep this info handy. Thanks.